# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roomId')

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to get the roomId from firestore but I'm stuck with this problem since last week I have tried different es6 syntax to overcome with but
no result. Below I have provided the code it shows the error on selectRoomId

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState: {
    roomId: null
  },
  reducers: {
    enterRoom: (state, action) => {
      state.roomId = action.payload.roomId;
    },
  },
});

export const { enterRoom } = appSlice.actions;
export const selectRoomId = state => state.app.roomId;
export default appSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: `I'm trying to get the roomId from firestore` How? How/where are you dispatching enterRoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread your state and update the roomId only

```
reducers: {
  enterRoom: (state, action) => {
    ...state,
    roomId: action?.payload?.roomId;
  },
},
```

Comment: Errors are accruing in this code at ...state

Comment: failed to compile at ...state reducers: {
    enterRoom: (state, action) => {
      ...state,
    roomId: action?.payload?.roomId;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Console log to check what you get from the store object by changing the state to

```
export const state = (state) => state;
```

this helped me, I was facing the same issue.

#Inside Component

```
const roomId = useSelector(state);
console.log(roomId);
```

#What I get from console

```
{user:{roomId: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the initial state is null, if you change it to 0 it will work. I did this, and it's working.